# MONTH invalid identifier in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

All ingredients purchased in November. Display the ingredient id, name, date ordered, quantity & unit (in one column), unit price, and total amount for each item. Order the result set by descending date ordered. Hint: total amount is quantity multiplied by unit price.

```
SELECT ingredient_id, ingredient_name, date_ordered, "Quantity & Unit" AS Quantity,
unit_price * quantity AS "Total Amount"
FROM ingredient
WHERE MONTH (date_ordered) = 11
ORDER BY 'date_ordered' DESC;
```

It keeps saying MONTH invalid identifier.

Answer (score 4):

There is multiple issues in your code:

- `MONTH` is not a valid function in oracle
- `'date_ordered'` is invalid as single quotes are not allowed for column names.

Your code should look like following:

> ```
> SELECT ingredient_id, ingredient_name, date_ordered, "Quantity & Unit" AS Quantity,
> unit_price * quantity AS "Total Amount"
> FROM ingredient
> WHERE extract (MONTH from date_ordered) = 11 -- used extract function
> ORDER BY date_ordered DESC; -- removed single quotes
> ```

Also note that this query will give all the records of november month regardless of the year.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

use `extract()` function

```
SELECT ingredient_id, ingredient_name, date_ordered, "Quantity & Unit" AS Quantity, unit_price * quantity AS "Total Amount" FROM ingredient WHERE extract(month from date_ordered) = 11 ORDER BY 'date_ordered' DESC;
```

Another option also is to use.

```
To_Char(date_ordered,'MM')
```